# Convert MS SQL datetime to Oracle varchar(32) interval

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server, oracle

I have a query against an MS SQL database that takes the resulting dataset and stores it in an Oracle database table which then gets joined to another Oracle table using the column `LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD_HH24_MI varchar(32)`.  I have converted the MS SQL datetime column `q.InTimeStart` as per below.

Is there a more efficient way of writing this line which takes datetime and finds beginning of 15min interval and stores as `varchar(32)`?

```
left(convert(varchar(32),convert(smalldatetime,floor(cast(q.InTimeStart as float)\*(24/.25))/(24/.25)),120),
len(convert(varchar(32),convert(smalldatetime,floor(cast(q.InTimeStart as float)*(24/.25))/(24/.25)),120)) -3) as LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD_HH24_MI,
```

Comment: what about `convert(varchar(32),convert(smalldatetime,floor(cast(q.InTimeStart as float)\*(24/.25))/(24/.25)),120)`? Don't you write that twice? Don't you wish you could do that just once?

Comment: @Pimgd Using the code you posted in your comment gives seconds...I need it with out the seconds hence the `left()` function.  Statically we can set a value but if your results are dynamic we would need `len()` as per my answer to my question.  I guess I really should ahve included that bit in my question that I want YYYY_MM_DD_HH24_MI no seconds, it may not be so clear just by the alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my data for `LABEL_YYY_MM_DD_HH24_MI` will always be the same length I can simply write:

```
left(convert(varchar(32),convert(smalldatetime,floor(cast(q.InTimeStart as float)*(24/.25))/(24/.25)),120),16) as LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD_HH24_MI,
```

If the results were of a dynamic length and we needed to remove the last three we would need to use `len(x,-3)`:

```
left(convert(varchar(32),convert(smalldatetime,floor(cast(q.InTimeStart as float)*(24/.25))/(24/.25)),120),
 len(convert(varchar(32),convert(smalldatetime,floor(cast(q.InTimeStart as float)*(24/.25))/(24/.25)),120)) -3) as LABEL_YYYY_MM_DD_HH24_MI,
```